# Who receives the change from stealth addresses?

Tags: stealth-address, change

Let's say I have the stealth addresses `S1` (unspent outputs = `10 XMR`), `S2` (unspent outputs = `20 XMR`), S3 (unspent outputs = `30 XMR`). Then I'm sending `35 XMR` of the outputs to another one-time public key `R`.

1. How does the reference wallet choose which of my stealth addresses will be used to have `35 XMR` as input? `S1` and `S3`, or `S2` and `S3`? Why?
2. To which address does the reference client send the change? To one of my stealth addresses (`S1`, `S2`, or `S3`) or to a new stealth address `S4`?

Comment: when you say "stealth address" - what do you mean?

Comment: The answer by @scoobybejesus is what I was looking for. I really meant [stealth addresses](https://getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/stealthaddress.html), and not [subaddresses](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/), like @ knaccc suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How does the reference wallet choose which of my stealth addresses will be used to have 35 XMR as input? S1 and S3, or S2 and S3? Why?

The wallet prefers older outputs (though someone can give you a better, code-based answer, I'm sure).  It does this because of the common heuristic that the newest ring member often indicates the true spender.

> 2. To which address does the reference client send the change? To one of my stealth addresses (S1, S2, or S3) or to a new stealth address S4?

The client will construct a new `S4` stealth address.  `S3` and `S1` and/or `S2` are fully spent/exhausted when used.  Outputs cannot be partially spent.  They are fully spent and change is returned.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the question might have been using the term stealth address to refer to subaddresses